# Facebook php sdk api takes forever to login/times out on production server

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

I'm using the example code on from the facebook SDK for facebook Authentication and I've been having no issues logging in on both the production server and the local server which I set up by adding a local ip as the mobile url.

However it now always takes a minimum of 30 seconds to login through facebook on the production server and 90% of the time it times out and produces a 504 Gateway Time-out error. After reloading the page, the session is logged in. I've tried rolling back to a version of the code where it was working and still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it was a problem with the php code. I utilised an encryption algorithm which takes a lot longer to run on the production server due to different system hardware and times out.